# What distribution covers proportions of multiple outcomes?

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, proportion

I had a friend ask me this question yesterday and I'm not certain of the answer. She has data where the variable of interest is a proportion but there are three categories. So $y_{i1} + y_{i2} + y_{i3} = 1$. She's in a maximum likelihood estimation class and needs to know how to find the likelihood function for these data, but I didn't know the correct distribution.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: For example, election outcomes with three parties. So for each year (observation), party 1 gets $y_{i1}$% of the vote, party 2 gets $y_{i2}$% of the vote and party 3 gets $y_{i3}$% of the vote, with those three totaling to 100%.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how does the data look like since it is not clear from your question?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems that you are describing one of two distributions, depending on what do you want to model and what is your data.

First one is the [categorical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution). It describes an event that can take $k$ possible outcomes, $x \in \{1,...,k\}$, with probabilities $p_1,...,p_k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1$. You can think of it as of [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with more than two categories. In this case your data is events and you are interested in probabilities.

On another hand, if you want to model the proportions of $k$ categories, than you could use [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). It is a multivariate distribution for $k$ variables $p_1,...,p_k$ such that each $p_i \in (0, 1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1$. You can think of it as of a multivariate [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). In this case your data are the proportions and you want to model their distribution.

Comment: @Alex does this answer your question?